# regex that matches positive integers and positive float values only

Tags: javascript, regex

for my project I need such a regular expression that matches price input that accepts:

```
(25.99, 15.5, 30.00, 0.5 or 50)
```

but does not accept:

```
(0, 0.00, -25.99, -50, $32 or  €32).
```

I have found some regular expressions but none of them meet my requirement.
following is my current regex but its not suiting my condition:

```
^(\$|)([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: Why do you need a regular expression for that? Just cast the values to float and check if they are > 0.0. If the cast fails, they also aren't what you're looking for.

Comment: Regular expressions, while they *could* do what you're asking, aren't meant for this. It would be much easier to check you've got a numeric expression, cast it to an appropriate type and then check it's positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(?![0.]+$)\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI5qF7/2)

Comment: cool but its accepting 15.000. More than 2 numbers after decimal are not required.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

Comment: great job bro.. 
but its not matching 15.5 :(

Comment: let me accept your answer just a couple of minutes remaining.

Comment: @DanishJamil: Is `0.5` not being accepted fine even though it is  a positive float value?

Comment: oho i am really sorry. 0.5 is needed. can you please edit your expression for me ?

Comment: ok then you can use [regex in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28960956/548225) for that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can make this without regexp?

```
val = parseFloat(str);
if (val > 0.0 ) {
  console.log('Correct');
} else {
  console.log('Wrong');
}
```

Comment: parseFloat will parse strings like ''123asd" => 123. What you actually need is Number. So it would be:

val = Number(str);
if (val > 0.0 ) {
  console.log('Correct');
} else {
  console.log('Wrong');
}